# Including typescript code from what file in another file

Tags: typescript

I have a main typescript file: Main.ts
In this file I use a class called Opleiding, which comes from another file.

The other file is referenced like

```
/// <reference path="../Models/Opleiding.ts" />
```

This works perfect for intellisense, but the code is not included. I wish for the code to be included so I only have to sent Main.ts to the client.

I tried changing the class to an export class and then intellisense suggests adding the following:

```
import Opleiding1 = require("../Models/Opleiding");
import Opleiding = Opleiding1.Opleiding;
```

This is accepted fine by intellisense but my browser says that require is undefined however. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, if I'm taking the right approach here or if this can be done simpler. I simply want the code included so I only have to send one file to the client. How can I accomplish this?

Comment: I dont think so u can use `require` in this way. u need `var sampleModule = require('modulename');`

Comment: @Smit: If I change the code to this, then intellisense does not recognize require

Comment: doesnt `import { Opleiding } from '../../../component'` dont put `.ts` work?

Comment: @Smit: Nope this does not work either. Im just gonna resort to adding classes via inline script tags I guess :P

Answer (score 0):

> The other file is referenced like

Don't do that. Use *modules* instead.

Module vs. global files are covered here : https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/project/modules.html

You will need a module bundler like webpack.
QuickStart: https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/quick/browser.html

If want to know all the horrible things that will happen if you don't use modules : https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/tips/outFile.html